# Number of ways to travel 20 blocks

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Ying lives at location A and works at location B as indicated below. Note that Ying needs to travel at least 20 blocks to go to work, namely 10 block south and 10 block east. Find a formula for the number of ways Ying can get from home to work (under the condition that she travels only 20 blocks).
This is the diagram:

[image: diagram]

I know it isn't that hard but something about this just makes me stuck. I am thinking that the answer is 20C10 but I don't think it is correct, and how I would arrive to that.

Comment: There are exactly 10 steps down, and 10 steps left.  How many ways can you arrange them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the answer is $\binom{20}{10}$.  Think of it this way: to go from $A$ to $B$, you have to exactly $20$ blocks, and $10$ of them must be going south, and $10$ of them east.  So you can think of a path as a sequence consisting of $20$ letters, $10$ of which are an $S$, and the other $10$ must be an $E$.  The number of such sequences is $\binom{20}{10}$.